# Is firebase hierarchical query on multiple ids better than simple query on single id?

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In a Q&A application with Firebase backend, a Post contains the question, answers and replies to each answer. The documents of collection `replies` have two fields: `questionId` and `answerId`

To get replies to a particular answer, there are two methods of query

- Method 1

```js
firebase.firestore().collection('replies').where('answerId','==',answerId).get()
```

- Method 2

```js
firebase.firestore().collection('replies').where('questionId','==',questionid).where('answerId','==',answerId).get()
```

Considering the number of questions is much greater than the number of answers, does method 2 have better performance than method1? Also possible delay caused by composite query is also considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The performance of a Firestore query is based on only one thing: the number of documents in the result set.  If your two queries return the same number of results, then they have the same overall performance. Adding or removing filters does not change this at all.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any reference to Firestore’s query performance?

Comment: Here's a talk I gave at Google I/O 2018.  https://youtu.be/9pwBgGgfHP8?t=208

Comment: Also the product launch blog: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/10/introducing-cloud-firestore.html